# Is it 'sleep problem' or 'sleeping problem'?

Tags: british-english

As the title indicates, I'm having trouble with the correct use of the word sleep in (for example) the following sentences:

- About 30 percent of adults regularly experience sleep(ing) problems.
- The record was reviewed for any notes made related to sleep(ing) problems.
- Sleep(ing) problems of patients appear to be under-recognised at admittance.

When should I use the -ing form of the word?

Comment: [@Flatter's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/400486/102510) covers the (subtle) difference very well. In all three examples you give, while either would work, I (BrEng) would probably go with _sleep_ since the specific problem is unspecified.

Comment: Sidenote: In contrast, if referring to a sleep disorder, i.e., a disgnosable medical condition, you would not use 'sleeping'. "Her doctor said she has a sleep disorder."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, but they express different things.

A "sleep problem" refers to a problem centered around sleep. A "sleeping problem" refers to a problem centered around (the act of) sleeping.

Some examples to highlight the differences:

> I have trouble falling asleep. I toss and turn for hours. Because it takes me so long to fall asleep, I always wake up late for work because my body still needs (and takes) 8 hours of sleep.

This person has trouble falling asleep, but eventually still gets the needed amount of sleep (which is why he is late for work: his body stays asleep for as long as it needs to).

This is a sleeping problem.

> I have no trouble falling asleep. However, I suffer from sleep apnea. Even though I have slept for 8 hours, my sleep is hindered so frequently that I physically feel like I've only had a short nap.
>   Note: apnea happens without the person realizing it.

This person has no trouble with falling asleep, or staying asleep. However, during his sleep, he suffers from apnea, which yields him considerably lower recuperation from sleeping compared to someone who does not have sleep apnea.

This is a sleep problem.

---

I've highlighted the difference, but please note that this is a very minute difference. More often than not, a sleeping problem causes (or is caused by) a sleep problem. They are often intertwined.

Unless there is a reason to make this distinction clear, I would argue that you could use either "sleeping problem" or "sleep problem", and be perfectly understandable.